# Inheritance and Friendship access. C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, access-control

I have the following query;

```
classB inherits from classA 
classC is friend of classB
```

Doesn't this mean classC should be able to access protected member of classA? Since classB inherits this from classA, an classC can access everything in class classB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `classC` should be able to access the protected `classA` subobject part of `classB`. It should *not* be able to access anything non-public from `classA` itself.

For example:

```
class C;

class A
{
protected:
  int i;
};

class B:
  public A
{
  friend class C;
};

class C
{
public:
  void foo(A& a, B& b)
  {
    // a.i = 3; // not allowed
    b.i = 3; // allowed, accesses the `i` of the `A` subobject of `B`
  }
};
```

Comment: This is the better answer for the original question.

Answer (score 8):

[My original answer was nonsense. Apologies for that. Thank you to @celtschk for pointing that out and providing the better answer.]

If `C` is a friend of `B`, it can access all of `B`'s members, whether private, public, or protected, and that includes the accessible (public and protected) members that are part of a base subobject:

```
struct A { protected: int a; };
struct B : A { private: int b; friend struct C; }

struct C
{
    B x;
    A w;

    void f()
    {
        x.a = 1; // fine
        x.b = 2; // fine

        // w.a = 0; /* Error, #1 */
    }

    friend struct D; // see below
};
```

However, friendship is neither transitive nor inherited: `C` is a friend of `B`, but not of `A` (see #1). Also, if `D` is a friend of `C`, then `D` doesn't get any of the access that `C`'s friendship to `B` affords it, so `D` cannot access `B`'s non-public members. Similarly, if `struct E : C` inherits from `C`, then `E` is also not a friend of `B` automatically:

```
struct D
{
     B y;
     void g()
     {
         // y.b = 3; /* Error! */
     }
};

struct E : C
{
     B z;
     void h()
     {
         // y.b = 4; /* Error! */
     }
}
```

Perhaps one can summarize what's going on in a few points:

- A derived class has access to all public and protected members of each base class.
- A friend of a class has access to all members of that class that are accessible to it (i.e. all members excluding private base members).
- Friendship is not inherited: If a class has a friend, that friendship does not apply to any of its base classes nor to any of its derived classes.
- A friend of a friend is not a friend.

Comment: It can also access the protected members of `B`'s `A` subobject. It just cannot access protected members of arbitrary `A` objects (but neither can `B`).

Comment: @celtschk: I think my answer is completely wrong. I need to revise it.

Comment: It's still not completely correct: It of course can access only those members of the `A` subobject which `B` itself can access. As written, it should also have access to `A`'s private members.